# i cant change the bg-color of cards when i toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the part of HTML code:

```html
<div class="card box bds">
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <p class="text">
      <img src="images/icon-facebook.svg" alt="fb" class="img" />@nathanf
    </p>
    <h1>1987</h1>
    <pre>F O L L O W E R S</pre>
    <p class="trend">
      <img src="images/icon-up.svg" alt="up" class="img1" />12 Today
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I created the switch button (it works fine):

```html
<div>
  <h4>Social Media Dashboard</h4>
  <p class="switch-text">Dark Mode</p>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch mode">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      class="custom-control-input"
      id="customSwitch"
      onclick="myFunction()"
    />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch"></label>
  </div>
  <p class="followers">Total Followers: 23,004</p>
</div>
```

This is the background color that I've added in light theme using css:

```css
.box {
  background-color: hsl(227, 47%, 96%);
}
```

and this is what I want to add after button is clicked:

```css
.dark-box {
  background-color: hsl(228, 28%, 20%);
}
```

here's the JS code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  var element1 = document.class('.card');
  element.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
  element1.classList.toggle('dark-box');
}
```

Now, when I click the switch the cards `background-color` remains the same, it won't change I want it to change to `.dark-box` theme, plz help

Comment: You have a typo. Its `document.querySelector('.card')` not `document.class('.card')`

Comment: ‘document.class()’ - are you sure that’s returning the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.class` is not a valid function.
use one of these instead:

- `document.querySelector('.card')`: returns the first element of class = card
- `document.querySelectorAll('.card')`: returns all the elements of class = card
- `document.getElementsByClassName('card')`: returns all the elements of class = card

And to apply the dark-box class to every one of the cards, you can do this:

```
function myFunction() {
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
  body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
  cards.forEach(card => card.classList.toggle('dark-box'));
}
```

Comment: yup i noticed this later, but still the problem that persists is i want to change the bg-color of the cards, and only the bg-color of whole page or document is changing, the bg-color of cards is not changing.  i want to swap between .box theme and .dark-box theme

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called `document.class()` in javascript, you can use `querySelector()` instead.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;;
  var element1 = document.querySelector('.card');
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  element1.classList.toggle("dark-box");
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: hsl(227, 47%, 96%);
}

.dark-box {
  background-color: hsl(228, 28%, 20%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card-deck">

    <div class="card box bds">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <p class="text"><img src="images/icon-facebook.svg" alt="fb" class="img">@nathanf</p>
        <h1>1987</h1>
        <pre>F O L L O W E R S</pre>
        <p class="trend"><img src="images/icon-up.svg" alt="up" class="img1">12 Today</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4>Social Media Dashboard</h4>
      <P class="switch-text">Dark Mode</P>
      <div class="custom-control custom-switch mode">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch" onclick="myFunction()">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="followers">Total Followers: 23,004</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the background color has changed, but i also want to change the background color of cards that iv'e made using bootstrap, the bg-color of cards is not changing

Comment: i've assigned .box class to all the cards i want to swap between .box theme and dark-box theme, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can pass event to your myFunction at onclick event handler.and then you can use it to toglle classList.Here is a quick example from codepen.

```
<div class="bg-change" onclick="myFunction(event);"></div>
```

```
.bg-change {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.dark-mode {
  background:darkblue;
}
```

```
function myFunction(event) {

 const { classList } = event.target;
  classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

you can play with it and change it according to your situation.

https://codepen.io/jesusfellas/pen/VwvjgrW

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, just edited the js code:

```
function darktheme() {
document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle("dark-mode");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[0].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[1].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[2].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[3].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[4].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[5].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[6].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[7].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[8].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[9].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[10].classList.toggle("dark-box");
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[11].classList.toggle("dark-box");
```

}

But still is there any way to make it shorter?

Comment: Check my answer for a cleaner way of doing this.